# How to add JSONArray to a set without iteration?

Tags: java, arrays

Hello I want to merge two JSONArray and remove duplicates. So here is my function

```
public JSONArray concatArray (JSONArray arr1, JSONArray arr2) {
    HashSet<JSONObject> set = new HashSet<JSONObject>();
    set.addAll(arr1);
    set.addAll(arr2);
    return new JSONArray(set);
```

}

However, I got

```
[javac] method Collection.addAll(Collection<? extends JSONObject>) is not applicable
[javac] (argument mismatch; JSONArray cannot be converted to Collection<? extends JSONObject>)
```

I have tried to iterate the arr and add to the set, but got same error for set.add(). I also tried to cast JSONArray to ArrayList, but it didn't work.

Thanks for helping!

Comment: yes! I searched a bit and seems that casting JSONObject to Object isn't good and causes errors, so I'm not sure how to deal with that

Comment: you can get the values as list using the ```getValuesAs``` and then add to the set, which should give you a set of unique items.

Comment: yeah thank you for reminding me to convert it to list:)

Answer (score 0):

So I figured it out. Converting it as list and then collection makes things work, since Set.addAll() requires Collection as the parameter

```
    set.addAll((Collection)arr1.toList());
    set.addAll((Collection)arr2.toList());
```